# Syntax error in WHERE clause (CAST required?)

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Book(article int, subArticle numeric);
```

2nd field - subArticle contains subarticles of an article, so that 1st article has 1.1, 1.2, etc. subarticles

Table has values like:

```
(1, 1.1),
(2, 1.2);
```

so that 2nd row is incorrect - 2nd article cannot have '1.2' subarticle. It has '2.1',... subarticles.

I run the following query to compare and leave only those lines, where article part within 'subarticle' field ('1' from '1.2') corresponds to real article value in according field 'article':

```
SELECT *
FROM Book
WHERE LEFT(subArticle, CHARINDEX('.', subArticle) - 1) = article;
```

But it fails syntax error in WHERE clause. Without WHERE clause - there is no error.
Do I need to cast values to compare them? I've tried, but no success either. What will be the correct cast then?

P.S. using sqlite3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use SQL Server syntax with SQLite
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

```
select  *
from    Book
where   substr(subArticle,1,instr(subArticle,'.')-1) = article
```

Answer (score -1):

CharIndex is for strings ie. characters (hence the name). You cant use that on a numeric.

As `subArticle` seems that it should be an identifier I think the best option is to restructure your schema and not try to mangle this query until it works.

Really it seems that this should just be a recursive key that points back to itself  so its type should be `int`. I am not sure why you currently have a multi-part value in there. So if you have control of your schema and you are allowed then change it / rethink it.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean (I'm SQL-beginner).
I need to indent subarticles from articles, so I have this structure - article 1: subarticle 1.1, etc.
And if I got it correctly, '1.1' cannot be represented as int, but can be as numeric